# Show that $\partial f (B) \ne f(\partial B)$

Tags: calculus, general-topology, multivariable-calculus, proof-writing, solution-verification

I'm trying to solve the following exercise, but I get exactly the negation of the thesis!

> Let us consider the function $$\boldsymbol{x} = \boldsymbol{f(p)}$$
> defined by
>
> $$x_1 = -\frac{1}{p_1 + 1} $$ $$ x_2 = p_2$$
>
> and consider the half-closed region of the Euclidean space $B= \{ \boldsymbol{p}: p_1 \geq 0 \}$.
>
> Show that $ f(\partial B) \ne \partial f (B)$

First of all, if $\boldsymbol{p} \in B$, then $\frac{-1}{p_1+1} \in [-1,0)$. Therefore

$$f(B) = \{(p_1,p_2): p_1 \in [-1,0), p_2 \in \mathbb{R} \} = [-1,0) \times \mathbb{R}$$

- Therefore $\partial f(B) = \{-1\} \times \mathbb{R}$

Now I want to compute $f(\partial B)$. First of all, $\partial B = \{0\} \times \mathbb{R}$, hence $$f (\partial B) = f(\{0\} \times \mathbb{R})$$ Now, since $p_1 = 0$ I obtain that $x_1=-1$ and $p_2$ is just a real number.

- Therefore $f (\partial B) = \{-1 \} \times \mathbb{R}$

So I obtain exactly the opposite of my thesis... and it's weird. Where am I wrong?

Comment: You forgot the boundary at $x_1 = 0$ for the first one. In essence the second set is connected while the first is not.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Uhm, but we have $x_1=0$ just in the limit, right? I mean, $\lim_{p_1 \rightarrow + \infty } \frac{-1}{p_1+1}=0$, but there's no point $p_1$ such that $x_1 =0$...what am I missing?

Comment: Does a set always contain its boundary?

Comment: @NinadMunshi Could you please be more explicit? I'm not following you

Comment: The points don't need to be contained in the set to be considered a boundary. Otherwise there would be nothing special about the  notion of a closure or a closed set in a metric space.

Comment: So you mean that $f(B)=[-1,0) \times \mathbb{R}$  and when I take the boundary I have also to take the $0$. 

But, by definition, by definition of boundary, the boundary of $f(B)$ is $$ [-1,0) \times \mathbb{R}  \setminus (0,\infty) \times \mathbb{R}$$, i.e. the set minus the interior... and I don't have the $0$ included in this way @NinadMunshi

Comment: I got my error: the boundary is the closure minus the interior, and the closure of $f(B)$ is $[-1,0] \times \mathbb{R}$, right? @NinadMunshi

Comment: @NinadMunshi Am I right now?

Comment: Yes that is correct.